# How to change a route name rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

I changed the routing of `posts#index` to match `blog` and I now get `/blog` in the URL which I was trying to accomplish.

I've tried several different things to get my actual blog post which the route currently looks something like `/posts/this-is-a-test` to also use `blog` rather than `posts` in the URL.
Below is my current **route** file. I am using the `friendly_id` gem, if that makes any difference in answering this question.

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments
end

  resources :contacts, only: [:new, :create]

  root "pages#home"

  get "/home", to: "pages#home", as: "home"
  get "about" => 'pages#about'
  get "pricing" => 'pages#pricing'
  get "contact_us" => 'pages#contact_us'
  match 'blog', to: 'posts#index', via: :all
end
```

Comment: @kiddorails thank you for cleaning up my question. I'm just starting to use stack more frequently and getting familiar with all the formatting. Reviewing your edits has been helpful in seeing where I can improve. Out of curiosity, why would you edit out a Thank you at the end of my question to show appreciation to folks in the community?

Comment: I am glad that it is helping you to grasp the question formatting etc. Personally, I wish to directly look and understand the question requirements; your 'thank-you' note was bigger than a line and was repeating the context of the question, so I removed it :). You could always attach just 'Thanks' or 'Thank you!' in your question though :)

Comment: Fair enough. Thank you for the answer below.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

[`path`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) option along with resource must help.

```
resources :posts, :path => 'blogs' do
  resources :comments
end
```

This will change all `/posts` and `/post` to `/blogs/` and `/blog`.

If you want to change your route's helper methods such as `posts_path` to `blogs_path` and `new_post_path` to `new_blog_path` etc, you can change it with [`as`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-the-named-helpers) tag.

```
resources :posts, :path => 'blogs', :as => 'blogs' do
  resources :comments 
end
```

Or yet better, you can specify the controller and route `blogs` directly as:

```
resources :blogs, controller: 'posts' do
  resources :comments
end
```

This is the awesomeness of Rails! :)

Comment: You'll also want `as` if you want to rename your path helpers to `blog` also

Comment: @kiddorails The only question now is how to get the views to load up from `views/blogs` instead of `views/posts`?

Answer (score 1):

This helped me, from [official guides documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#generating-paths-and-urls-from-code), add this in your `routes.rb` file:

```rb
get '/patients/:id', to: 'patients#show', as: 'patient'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
match 'blog/:id' => 'posts#show'
```

should work. But if you want to match every method in posts controller to blog (and you don't want to use the posts path), I would just rename the controller to blog instead and add resource :blog in the routes.